# Show alert after app start

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a problem with showing alert after application start. I am using Notification Center observe notification error and find current visible view controller to show alert on it. This work when I handle error after start an app, but if I want to show this error just after start an app, it does not happen. 
My code for app delegate:

```
func listenForRealmErrorNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: MyDataModelDidFailNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: { notification in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Internal alert", comment: "Internal error header"),
                                      message: NSLocalizedString("There was an error while working whith your data", comment: "Internal error description") + "\n\n" + NSLocalizedString("Press OK to terminate the app. Sorry for the inconvenience", comment: "Internal error excuses"),
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Agree button on internal error"), style: .default, handler: {_ in
            let exeption = NSException(name: NSExceptionName.internalInconsistencyException, reason: "Realm error", userInfo: nil)
            exeption.raise()
        })
        alert.addAction(action)
        print("***Observe error")
        self.viewControllerForShowingAlert().present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
func viewControllerForShowingAlert() -> UIViewController {
    let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController!
    return topViewController(from: rootViewController)
}

func topViewController(from controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    if controller is UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(from: (controller as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController!)
    }
    if controller is UITabBarController {
        return topViewController(from:(controller as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController!)
    }
    if let presentedViewController = controller.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(from:presentedViewController)
    }

    return controller
}
```

And code for post notification:

```
func fatalRealmError(_ error: Error) {
print("***Fatal error with dataBase: \(error)")
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyDataModelDidFailNotification, object: nil)
}
```

UPDATE:
Initiating my data source in delegate:

```
    func initialDataSource() {
    do {
        dataSource = try UserDataSource()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        fatalRealmError(error)
    }
}
```

And here I have set am observer:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    customizeAppearance()

    listenForRealmErrorNotification()
    initialDataSource()
    let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let rootContentController = rootViewController.viewControllers[0] as! YourFoodViewController
    rootContentController.dataSource = dataSource

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    return true
}
```

Comment: fatalRealmError is called from which controller or class?

Comment: It called in appDelegate too when I catch error at init data base

Comment: Can you provide more info about what kind of viewController is visible when you open the app? Is it presented viewController?

Comment: It's a collection view controller, but it's embedded in navigation controller

Comment: @D. Pass as you said fatalRealmError is called in appDelegate, so in which function you call fatalRealmError?

Comment: I have updated description with this info

Comment: Statement mentioned in your question **_This work when I handle error after start an app, but if I want to show this error just after start an app_** is confusing. Can you post some screenshot or video to show the issue?

Comment: I can post screenshot of the message, but I don't think it will help. But if you want, I can do that. In those sentence I mean, that if I have such message not from initialDataSource(), but in other situation, not from appDelegate (while I catch error when save data, for example), everything works fine.